# Obj C Init not recognized in Swift (DBCamera)

Tags: objective-c, swift

When I write the bottom Swift code I get, "Extra argument in call." Is the syntax wrong or is there some other problem? Thanks.

Objective-C Initializer:

```
typedef void(^CameraSettingsBlock)(DBCameraView *cameraView, id container);
- (id) initWithDelegate:(id<DBCameraViewControllerDelegate>)delegate cameraSettingsBlock:(CameraSettingsBlock)block;
```

Swift Initialization:

```
var cameraContainer = DBCameraContainerViewController(delegate: self, cameraSettingsBlock:{
        (cameraView:DBCameraView, container:DBCameraContainerViewController) in
        cameraView.photoLibraryButton.hidden = true
})
```

Comment: Does it help if you make the second parameter of your block `AnyObject!` instead of `DBCameraContainerViewController`?

Comment: Also, when I get cryptic error messages from the Swift compiler about a function call, I try to make each parameter a `let` variable and then pass the variables in to the function. Often this will help me find which particular parameter is having the problem.

Comment: Switching it to AnyObject! doesn't fix the error. Apple's Intellisense doesn't show the cameraSettingBlock initializer as a callable function...

Comment: Can you paste the exact text of the error message?

Comment: Error message: http://i.imgur.com/NDbnb0F.png Intellisense started working after I restarted my computer and this is the function skeleton: http://i.imgur.com/DFtWENw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I had needed an ! with DBCameraView and needed to switch DBCameraContainerViewController to AnyObject!. Thanks to everyone!

```
var cameraContainer = DBCameraContainerViewController(delegate: self, cameraSettingsBlock:{
    (cameraView:DBCameraView!, container:AnyObject!) in
    cameraView.photoLibraryButton.hidden = true
})
```

Comment: nice... it was simple :)

Comment: @Antonio Yeah! Xcode can be very cryptic with its error messages, as Bill said.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use this code, making use of syntactic sugar to define a closure when it's the last parameter in a function:

```
var cameraContainer = DBCameraContainerViewController(delegate: self) { (cameraView, container) in
    cameraView!.photoLibraryButton.hidden = true
}
```

or more concisely:

```
var cameraContainer = DBCameraContainerViewController(delegate: self) { $0!.photoLibraryButton.hidden = true }
```

I both cases type inference is used to determine types. In the latter case, the `$0` is a shortcut for the first parameter passed to the closure.

Let me know if it works

Comment: They both result in the same error message (extra argument in the call). I wonder if it's an Xcode bug. Thanks though!

Comment: Imported the entire library for better testing, and I notice that: `CameraSettingsBlock` is not available (as if it were not defined), and the `init()` method with that block as last parameter doesn't show in intellisense. Weird, it looks like bridging is getting rid of both the typedef and that init method

Comment: That also explains the `Extra argument in call` error: from swift the `initWithDelegate:` method only is available, hence it complains because of the extra block parameter

Comment: It might be a bug though. I tried turning the _settingsBlock private class member (see .m file) into a public property, and intellisense doesn't show it - and ofc using it results in a compiler error due to unknown property

Comment: I see you've opened an issue on github - please report here any solution, I'm curios to know what's causing that.

Comment: I got it working! See below. Thanks a lot for the help!